# How to create multiple branch restrictions using Bitbucket api?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to automate the branch permissions setup using the bitbucket api but when I try to add multiple rules it doesn't overwrite the old rule (in case it exists). I'm creating 2 rules for a repository for one branch but if I re-run the api again with a little change in the rule, it will add the rule I added, instead of editing it the current rule.

I run this call:

```
curl -X POST -v -u "username:secret" -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.atl.bitbucket.bulk+json" https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/branch-permissions/2.0/projects/myproj/repos/myrepo/restrictions -d '[{ "type": "read-only","matcher": {"id": "master","displayId": "master","type": {"id":"PATTERN","name": "Pattern"}},"users": ["my.user"],"groups": ["StashAdmins"]},{ "type": "no-deletes","matcher": {"id": "master","displayId": "master","type": { "id":"PATTERN","name": "Pattern"}},"users": ["user.my"],"groups": []}]'
```

Then I wanted to overwrite the current branch permissions so I changed the first rule from read-only to pull-request-only, so I run :

```
curl -X POST -v -u "username:secret" -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.atl.bitbucket.bulk+json" https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/branch-permissions/2.0/projects/myproj/repos/myrepo/restrictions -d '[{ "type": "pull-request-only","matcher": {"id": "master","displayId": "master","type": {"id":"PATTERN","name": "Pattern"}},"users": ["my.user"],"groups": ["StashAdmins"]},{ "type": "no-deletes","matcher": {"id": "master","displayId": "master","type": { "id":"PATTERN","name": "Pattern"}},"users": ["user.my"],"groups": []}]'
```

but it added the new rule (pull-request-only) instead of editing the whole rule.

Does anyone know how to forces overwrite the branch restriction rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this Rest Api endpoint you can just create new restrictions as you can have several ones per repository and/or project.

See here for more: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.4.0/bitbucket-ref-restriction-rest.html#idp1

You first need to delete all restrictions which were created before and then post a new one. To get all restrictions per repository you will need to use this endpoint:

`GET /rest/branch-permissions/2.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/restrictions`
https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.4.0/bitbucket-ref-restriction-rest.html#idp3

And then you can delete them one by one with this one:

`DELETE /rest/branch-permissions/2.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/restrictions/{id}`
https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/6.4.0/bitbucket-ref-restriction-rest.html#idp6

Comment: And what about Bitbucket Cloud?